# What is the purpose of IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, state-machine

Interface `IAsyncStateMachine` can be used only by compiler, and is used in generating state machine for async methods. Interface has `SetMachineState` - configures the state machine with a heap-allocated replica(from msdn).

I used `ILSpy` to decompile code and discover generated state machine and mentioned that implementation of `SetMachineState` function is always empty, like this

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <GetResult>d__1 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    //some fields to hold state

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    { ... }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //Method is empty
    }
}
```

One more thing, generated state machine is a `class` not a `struct` as stated everywhere.

So, the question is: What the purpose of `SetStateMachine` function of `IAsyncStateMachine` interface, where is it used?

Original async function:

```
private static async Task<int> GetResult()
{
    var task = GetSomeData();
    DoSomeWork();
    return await task;
}
```

Comment: what is the async code you used to *decompile* this? Most likely you just had no bind

Comment: added original async function

Comment: yep - I think you don't need any state-machine for that - think of it: you can just as well return `tasḱ` directly and the compiler might know this- add at least one more async function/task and try again

Comment: or switch the `await task` in front of `DoSomeWork()` this should force a state-transition as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because you're looking at a `debug` build and not a `release` one.

Making the state-machine a struct is a compiler optimization. It enables not allocating memory when the awaitable is already completed when awaited. That optimization isn't necessary while debugging and it makes implementing debugging features in Visual Studio harder.

If you look at the same code compiled in `release` the state-machine will indeed be a struct and the `SetStateMachine` method will not be empty as this is the method that moves the state-machine from the stack to the heap:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
private struct <GetResult>d__1 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;
    ...

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        this.<>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}
```